# changing variable on app close

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to change value of variable which  will stop some threads,what I want is to change that value when you close the app, I mean when you click in the X and it gets closed.

I am trying something but it does not work:

```
 def on_request_close(self):
    close()
    print("awdw")
    self.textpopup(title='Exit', text='Are you sure?')
```

and this is my `close()` method called on `on_request_close()`:

```
def close(self):
    print("Cerrando")
    print(str(self.exit))
    self.exit = False
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do something like `Window.bind(on_request_close=on_request_close)`.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

1. To display the Popup widget before Window close, append `return True` to `on_request_close()` method.
2. Add `Window.bind(on_request_close=self.on_request_close)` into `build()` method.

Please refer to example for details.

[Window » on_request_close](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.window.html)

```
on_request_close(*largs, **kwargs)
```

> Event called before we close the window. If a bound function returns
>   True, the window will not be closed.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window


class MyApp(App):
    exit = BooleanProperty(True)

    def build(self):
        Window.bind(on_request_close=self.on_request_close)
        return Label(text="Hello world")

    def on_request_close(self, *largs, **kwargs):
        print('on_request_close:')
        self.close()
        print("awdw")
        self.textpopup(title='Exit', text='Are you sure?')
        return True

    def close(self):
        print("Cerrando")
        print(str(self.exit))
        self.exit = False

    def textpopup(self, title='', text=''):
        print('textpopup:')
        box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        box.add_widget(Label(text=text))
        mybutton = Button(text='OK', size_hint=(1, 0.25))
        box.add_widget(mybutton)
        popup = Popup(title=title, content=box, size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
        mybutton.bind(on_release=self.stop)
        popup.open()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - Popup widget]